# Return URL of ubercart after successful payment

Tags: 7, ubercart

I created a third party payment gateway integrate with ubercart. I manage to redirect to third party payment gateway once check out. I am able to return url but I cant change statue to complete? I get this info from: http://nmc-codes.blogspot.ca/2012/07/how-to-create-custom-ubercart-payment.html

I set my return url as this: http://www.example.com/cart/mypayment/complete", but page not found.

What should I do?

Here is my code:

```
 function uc_mypayment_menu() {
    $items['cart/mypayment/complete'] = array(
    'title' => 'Payment Complete',
    'page callback' => 'uc_mypayment_complete', 
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),  
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function uc_mypayment_complete() {

  if (empty($_POST)) {
    watchdog('My Payment Gateway',
             'Received an empty or incomplete response.  Response details: @request_details',
             array('@request_details' =>  print_r($_POST,true)), WATCHDOG_ERROR);

    return 'There was a problem with your payment';
  }

  if ($_POST['status'] == 'SUCCESS') {


    uc_payment_enter($order_id, 'my_pay_gateway', $amount, $order->uid, NULL, $orderId);
    uc_cart_complete_sale($order, variable_get('uc_new_customer_login', FALSE));

    return 'Thank you for your purchase';
  }
}
```

Comment: add destination url after "?"

Comment: @Adi, I had edited my question